# Can't install my simple test library via CMake CLI

Tags: c++, cmake

I'm trying to build and install my test library with CMake which consist of CMakeLists.txt and one class.
I follow the example given [by this link](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/guide/user-interaction/index.html#software-installation).
I can successfully run the following commands:

```sh
$ cmake .. -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=C:/my/path/install
$ cmake --build .
```

Then I'm trying to perform the install command:

```sh
$ cmake --build . --target install
```

and I get the error:

```
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.8.2+25e4d540b for .NET Framework
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

MSBUILD : error MSB1009: Project file does not exist.
Switch: INSTALL.vcxproj
```

This is not my first CMake project but the it is the first time I'm trying to install it.

Configuration: Windows 10 x64, MSVC 2019 x64, CMake 3.19.0, VS code

Comment: If you do not have any `install(...)` commands in your CMakeLists.txt the `INSTALL.vcxproj` won't be created. Please add your CMakeLists.txt to your question for further adivse.

Comment: thank you! I'm going to try